# Microsoft Word table column narrower than content control name

Tags: ms-word, openxml, word-contentcontrol

How do you make the name of an xml-bound content control wrap when you add it inside a table in a Word doc? Just adding a plain-text control makes it so that the column won't get narrower than the name of the content control. With regular text, you would just add a hyphen, but that would break an xml-bound content control I think.

Example use case: I might want to show a quantity value in a table that will only be 2 characters or less (e.g. values 1 - 99), but because the field is called "quantity" I can't make the column narrower than to accommodate all 8 characters in the word quantity.

Comment: It's unclear what kind of information you're looking for with this. Are you working with code or in the UI? You tag openxml but show no code or xml we can build on. Why not set an exact column width?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to edit the XML, you can manually insert linefeed characters in the w:alias tag of **/word/document.xml**:

```
Title of the Content Control is&#10;very long as a consequence
```

[image]

But normally, you would place the "Quantity" text in the **table header row** and leave the CC Title blank.